# How can I prevent the offset multiplier in plot_surface from exceeding figure limits?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, surface, matplotlib-3d

I am using matplotlib to created 3d plots using plot_surface but ran into the issue that when scientific notation is needed, the multiplier is offset to the point that it no longer appears in the figure.  This can be reproduced using this example in the matplotlib documentation https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/offset.html
Even the image in the documentations shows the problem.
I am using matplotlib version 3.7.1 in python 3.11

Any idea how to fix this issue?  I have decades of experience with Matlab but am new to python and definitely not qualified to go into matplotlib source code.

I have attempted turning off the offset with this code `ax.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)`
but it seems to have no effect

Here is the code from the matplotlib that reproduces the issue:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(projection='3d')

X, Y = np.mgrid[0:6*np.pi:0.25, 0:4*np.pi:0.25]
Z = np.sqrt(np.abs(np.cos(X) + np.cos(Y)))

ax.plot_surface(X * 1e5, Y * 1e5, Z, cmap='autumn',cstride=2, rstride=2)

ax.set_xlabel("X label")
ax.set_ylabel("Y label")
ax.set_zlabel("Z label")
ax.set_zlim(0, 2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Trenton McKinney.  I have added an example that reproduces the issue with the multiplier.

Comment: Thanks for the response Trenton.  In the figure that you generated the issue appears.  If you look at the bottom left of the figure you can see the top part of the the multiplier (1e5) that should appear in the x and y axes.

Comment: You can use `ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)`. It looks like that artifact is even in the example code on the matplotlib website.

Comment: Yes, if you rotate the figure you can see more of it.  It is the 1e5 multiplier that should appear in the x and y axes but for some reason it is offset out of the image.  You can see that that in the code x and y are incremented by 1e5 but that does not show in the figure.  X only goes from 0 to 15 and Y from 0 to 12.

Comment: I modified the code to multiply x and y by 1e5 instead of adding.  I have also attached the figure generated by the code after rotation and you can see the two 1e6 multipliers way off target.  The useOffset=False makes no difference in this case.